# mailcore2 How to forward/reply email iOS

Tags: ios, mailcore2

According to ***MCOMessageBuilder.h***, we can send a message using SMTP as follows:

```
MCOMessageBuilder * builder = [[MCOMessageBuilder alloc] init];
[[builder header] setFrom:[MCOAddress addressWithDisplayName:@"Hoa V. DINH" mailbox:@"hoa@etpan.org"];
NSArray * to = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[MCOAddress addressWithDisplayName:@"Gael Roualland" mailbox:@"gael@etpan.org"]];
[[builder header] setTo:to];
[[builder header] setSubject:@"A nice picture!"];
[builder setHTMLBody:@"<div>Here's the message I need to send.</div>"];
[builder addAttachment:[MCOAttachment attachmentWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/foo/Pictures/image.jpg"]];
NSData * rfc822Data = [builder data];
```

But if I want to forward or reply to other email, which property should I set?
I tried several methods like set **relatedAttachments**,**htmlInlineAttachments** etc., but it has no effect.

I wonder if I can combine htmlBody from other email with current sending content as HTML, and then set setHTMLBody?

Comment: Take a look at what other emails looks like. They usually use <blockquote>.

Comment: @DinhViêtHoà I do not understand what you mean.JavaMail use multipart,but how mailcore2 can set?