# How to send a reply to an email using MailCore2 in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mailcore2

I'm trying to use MailCore2 in my Swift iOS app, and at the moment; am trying to understand how to reply to an email.

Currently have something working where I can send new email messages, but am trying to figure out how to reply to an existing email.

I've seen a few different questions here asking for the same thing:

- [mailcore2 How to forward/reply email iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044066/mailcore2-how-to-forward-reply-email-ios)
- [MailCore2 Reply / Forward](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007826/mailcore2-reply-forward)
- [replyAllHeaderWithExcludedRecipients seems not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32469030/replyallheaderwithexcludedrecipients-seems-not-working)

But so far, I've not come across anything that actually ends up answering the question. Any help here appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out eventually:

```
var emailToReplyTo: MCOIMAPMessage!
emailToReplyTo = //the email message that you want to reply to 
let reply = emailToReplyTo.header.reply(withExcludedRecipients: [])
let builder = MCOMessageBuilder()
builder.header = reply
builder.header.from = MCOAddress(displayName: "My Name", mailbox: "myemail@gmail.com")
builder.htmlBody = "Message body!"
```